# Specify field in Find query

Tags: couchdb, pouchdb, couchdb-mango

I'm using PouchDB 7 with the find plugin.
I would like to retrieve specific information by using mango query. But when a specific value is inside an object, the previous value is not returned.

> Example

```
{
    "selector": {
        "docType": "client"
    },
    fields: [
        "_id",
        "docData.name",
        "docData.lastName",
        "docData.address.street",
        "docData.age"
    ]
}
```

> The example return:

```
[
    {
        "_id": 1,
        "docData": {
            "age": 21
        }
    },
    {
        "_id": 2,
        "docData": {
            "age": 22
        }
    }
]
```

But that same mango query, returns the document correctly on couchdb. Does anyone know what can it be?

Comment: why dont you add only `docData` in the `fields` array??? Do you need only specific values from `docData` object?

Comment: Yes Exactly, I only need specific docData properties. For if I recover everything I will have more information than necessary needed in my application.

Comment: The strange thing is that this syntax works on couchdb and does not work on pouchdb, since both use the mango query,